# Changing the file name of a Sqlite3 database connection, while keeping keeping entire data

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have something like....:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
...
...
conn.close()
```

My db_path could be ":memory:" or a real path, so how would I change it to say "newFile.db"
while keeping all of my data from my work.

In short I need to go from

1. :memory: to a_new_path.db
2. old_path.db to new_path.db

I know they're both one in the same.....

Anyways, i have no clue. I skimmed through the docs, but without any luck. Maybe I missed something.

I don't know if it helps, but I'm trying to implement File menu functions: open new(:memory:), open existing(existing file), save and save as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just change the file name of a database.

Python's built-in database API does not have any mechanism to copy databases; you would have to copy the file itself, which is not possible for in-memory databases.

If you use [APSW](https://code.google.com/p/apsw/) instead, you can use the [backup API](http://apidoc.apsw.googlecode.com/hg/backup.html).

Comment: Hmmm, thats a bummer. Plus, I didn't know about APSW. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: It is not safe to rename SQLite databases anyway.  In addition to the main database file there are several additional files that may be present (journals, WAL, shm etc).  If those also aren't renamed then your database will end up corrupted.  The **only** way is to use the backup api.  (Disclosure: I'm the APSW author)